# Don't work composer in PHP 7.0

Tags: php, composer-php

Don't work composer in PHP 7.0

I insert this command to the terminal:

**$sudo composer require cocur/slugify**

In the directory is created only one empty file composer.json

My OS: 
Ubuntu 14.04

My PHP:

```
PHP 7.0.1-5+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.4.0RC2, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

> Sorry, the application php7.0 has stopped unexpectedly
>
> php7.0 crashed with sigsegv in xdebug_var_export

Comment: Do you mean there is a `vendors/cocur/slugify` empty directory?

Comment: Also, composer should normally not be run as sudo.

Comment: ~/sites/testphp/slugify $composer require cocur/slugify  OUTPUT:                                         You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Created only file composer.json

Comment: Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Executing command (/home/artamonov/sites/testphp): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (/home/artamonov/sites/testphp): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/home/artamonov/sites/testphp): hg branch
Executing command (/home/artamonov/sites/testphp): svn info --xml
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Have you tried `composer install` after that?

Comment: php7.0 crashed with sigsegv in xdebug_var_export

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and congratulations! You just discovered the hard way what Composer [officially recommends](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#xdebug-impact-on-composer) (for a different reason): disable xdebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the error, you might simply disable the Zend Extension "xdebug" for Composer runs:

`;zend_extension = "/path/to/xdebug.so"` in `php.ini`.

Comment: Yes, I disabled xdebug and made alias for php. Everything works very good.

Comment: Glad i could help :)